# FlexPrintJob creates extra border lines

Tags: apache-flex, layout, printing, flex3

For some reason, when I try to execute a FlexPrintJob I get an extra border on the bottom or the right side of the print out (and sometimes both). I have no idea what the border is, where it comes from or how to get rid of it. I've tried changing the background colour of the various items to try to see if that colour will show up, but it always stays the same shade of grey.

At the same time, I also get

> Warning: Filter will not render.  The DisplayObject's filtered dimensions (3324, 1740) are too large to be drawn.

in the console. I don't know what it thinks is 3324, 1740. The mx:Box object I pass to it is about 600x100.

I'm using Flex 3.5.

Comment: Try putting a mask on the object to make sure it doesn't break out of it's dimensions with an effect or something. Also be careful of any items on the display list that are invisible (I don't believe the print job handles alpha values).

Comment: Ok, mask... I've not heard of that member before and I'm not sure how to use that, and reading Adobe's manual doesn't make it clear how. How do you recommend I use a mask?

There isn't a whole lot to the box. It's just
<mx:VBox id="boxPrint" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" borderColor="#FFFFFF">
and then
<mx:Box id="box" />